# Python 2.7 cannot find module Request from urllib.request

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib, python-import

When trying to import `Request` from `urllib.request` in Python 2.7, it's unable to find the package.

```
>>> from urllib.request import Request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named request
```

Comment: `urllib.request` is a Python 3 module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `urllib.request` module in Python 2, that module [only exists in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html).

Use [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) instead:

```
from urllib2 import Request
```

From the top of the module documentation:

> **Note:** The `urllib2` module has been split across several modules in Python 3 named `urllib.request` and `urllib.error`. The `2to3` tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.

If you are following some kind of tutorial or course, you may want to install Python 3 and continue using that version; the code you are trying to execute is clearly designed for Python 3.